# Change certain value of a JSON object

Tags: ruby, json, hash

This is the raw JSON object:

```
{"num":11,"content":"puss\n","percentage":0}
```

I want to replace `11` with `12`, namely change the value of "num".

```
{"num":12,"content":"puss\n","percentage":0}
```

Please describe it in Ruby language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember that Stack Overflow isn't a "write code for me" site; We really want to see evidence of your attempt to solve a problem prior to asking a question. How to unserialize JSON, and how to access values in the resulting array or hash, are questions often asked on Stack Overflow, so how to do it is a quick search away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert the raw json string into hash object using [`JSON#parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse). Change the hash object as you want. Then convert it back to json string using [`JSON#dump`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-dump):

```
require 'json'

raw_json = '{"num":11,"content":"puss\n","percentage":0}'
h = JSON.parse(raw_json)
h['num'] += 1
JSON.dump(h)  # => '{"num":12,"content":"puss\n","percentage":0}'
```