# Change the value of a json object in Node.js with process.env

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I'm learning Node.js atm and am trying to change the response of an app request, depending on certain parameters. For instance if I set the MESSAGE_STYLE to uppercase I want the value of the (single) key in the json object to become uppercase. However I can't seem to change the object. I'm not reading the value as a string it seems, so to toUpperCase() doesn't work.

After reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454553/change-certain-value-of-a-json-object) I tried JSON.parse and then JSON.dump but that didn't work either (unless I did it wrong). Help is much appreciated!

**THIS DOESN'T WORK**

```
process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE='uppercase';

app.get('/json', function(req, res){
var response = res.json({
  "message": "Hello json"
});

if(process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE==='uppercase'){
  response.message.toUpperCase();
  return response;
} else {
  return response;
  };
});
```

**BUT THIS DOES**

```
process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE='uppercase';

app.get('/json', function(req, res){

if(process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE==='uppercase'){
  res.json({
  "message": "HELLO JSON"
})
} else {
    res.json({
  "message": "Hello json"
})
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the `response` object but it needs to be overridden to get your latest changes in `response.message` attribute.

```
process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE='uppercase';

app.get('/json', function(req, res){
// Variable assignment as object
var response = {
  "message": "Hello json"
};

if(process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE==='uppercase'){
  //Override message attribute value based on condition
  response.message = response.message.toUpperCase();  
}

return res.json(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd actually already tried assigning a new value with the equals operator but hadn't thought of returning the res.json afterwards (though a simple step). Sometimes the obvious can slip right through..

Comment: It happens some-cases. Best wishes.